# Использование Google Widevine DRM в iOS-приложении

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, exoplayer

В моём iOS-приложении мне нужно воспроизвести DASH-видео, защищённое с помощью Google Widevine DRM. Данная технология не является родной для Apple, потому я ищу стороннюю библиотеку. Подскажите, существует ли какое-нибудь бесплатное решение для данной проблемы? Насколько мне известно, в Android-приложениях в таких случаях можно воспользоваться ExoPlayer.

Comment: Посмотрите на этот проект https://github.com/BCdmcgaffin/WidevineSampleApp, возможно подойтет

Comment: @0rt Благодарю за ответ, однако в приведённом Вами примере используется Brightcove Player SDK, а оно не является бесплатным. Мне бы что-нибудь на основе SDK с открытым кодом.